# GParted unable to read contents of FAT32 file system on micro sd card

Tags: 22.04, gparted

GParted unable to read contents of FAT32 file system on micro sd card. I have tried it with brand new 128 GB card as well as previously used 16GB card.
I have installed mstools package; dosfstools package was already installed.
Computer is a month old one with Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop installed.
[image]

---

The micro sd card is readable on Ubuntu and whatever operating system my newly-purchased dash cam uses. I have dosfstools & mtools packages already installed. The popup appears even for a 16GB SD Card.

Comment: Was flash drive used with Windows? And bitlocker or windows fast startup/hibernation turned on. That can set a hibernation bit preventing access with Linux driver.